# Simple script for moving a file by ID into a Folder by ID in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Totally new at this stuff and after spending an evening searching I can’t seem to find an answer that works.

I have used a script I found online to build out a folder structure for 600 different locations (and give me the ID of each folder in a google sheet), and then a separate script to get the ID of 600 PDFs and I now need to move each PDF to the correct location file.

I have a google sheet with each location, the folder ID and the File ID but I don’t know how to automate google taking that specific file ID from column B and moving it to the folder ID in column C

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script shall move the file `getById` from current folder to the folder specified by ID. The Data sheet should have File ID in Column B and Folder ID in column C and the user running this script shall have write access to the folder ID

```js
function fileMover() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for (var i = 1; i < ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var folderId = ss.getRange("C" + i).getValue();  //column C of sheet shall have Folder ID
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var fileId = ss.getRange("B" + i).getValue(); //column B of sheet shall have File ID
    var files = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    files.moveTo(folder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am very appreciative of the support.