# Apps Script - Move file to folder based on IDs

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to automate to move certain files to specific folders using Apps Script. I already created functions to create custom folders, get it's IDs, get Files IDs and export it to a Sheets. So now I have a Sheets with 4 columns: File Name, File IDs, Folder Name and Folder IDs, I need a function to move each file ID to its correspondent Folder ID.

I already tried to use the function below, found in this question [Simple script for moving a file by ID into a Folder by ID in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65303264/simple-script-for-moving-a-file-by-id-into-a-folder-by-id-in-google-drive) but I keep getting the error `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp. fileMover`. What can be wrong?

Script as mentioned above:

```
function fileMover() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url_sheets)
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("match ids")

  for (var i = 1; i < ws.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var folderId = ws.getRange("F2:F" + i).getValue();  
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    var fileId = ws.getRange("D2:D" + i).getValue(); 
    var files = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    files.moveTo(folder);
  }
}
```

Sheet sample below (blurred some parts due to sensitive info)
[image: Sheet sample below (blurred some parts due to sensitive info)]

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample table for your Google Sheets? I assume `getRange("F" + i)` outputs "F1" cell which could possibly be a column header that is why `DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)` is generating the error.

Comment: Are your variables showing the proper information if you enter debug mode? See these on the left...

Comment: @CenturyTuna sure, edited the post to include a sample, I also edited the code to getRange("F2:F" + i) to exclude headers, but I kept getting the same error.

Comment: @pgSystemTester Yes, I tried using debug mode, no info is showed.

Comment: Found the issue, on  "for (var i = 1; i < ws.getLastRow(); i++)" the right value for i is 2, and keep the "getRange("F" + i)", thank you for all comments guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function fileMover() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url_sheets)
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("match ids");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(r[5]);
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(r[3]);
    files.moveTo(folder);
  });
}
```

If it does not work for some of your files then enable the Advanced Drive API and use this:

```
function fileMover() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url_sheets)
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("match ids");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(r[5]);
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(r[3]);
    Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": r[5]}]}, r[3])
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cooper ! It was a more complex approach but it worked as well. I'll mark it as accepted answer since it can be helpful on the future for other people.